# MS Edge: CSS Filter causes CSS Animation to be shaky

Tags: css, css-animations, microsoft-edge

Please see: https://codepen.io/se7en/pen/QmLWNK

In MS Edge 16 adding a css drop shadow to an icon using something like `filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px red);` causes the css animation to be shaky.

This doesn't seem to happen in any other browser.

CSS:

```
.icon {
  width: 24px;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 12px 12px 0;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px red); 
}

@keyframes rotate{
  0%{
    transform:rotate(0deg)
  }
  to
  {
    transform:rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```